# Populate JPlayer playlist from XML generated from PHP, MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, xml, jplayer, playlist

I'm trying to create a dynamic playlist for JPlayer from XML generated from a .php file.  This is the code for the .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1", cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1" };
    var playlist = []; // Empty playlist
    var options = { swfPath: "../js", supplied: "ogg, mp3" };
    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);

$.get ("xml_audio.php", {}, function (xml) {
    $('Track', xml).each (function (i) {

    var   title = $(this).attr('title');
    var   track_name = $(this).attr('track_name');
    var   mp3 = 'audio/' + track_name + '.mp3';
    var   ogg = 'audio/' + track_name + '.ogg';

    var obj = ({title: title, mp3: mp3, ogg:ogg});
        alert(obj);
    playlist.push (obj);
    });  /*end of xml .each loop */
}); /* end of xml .get loop */
}); /**end of document.ready loop */
```

The XML is outputting correctly, and the variables are being picked up.  The problem seems to be in the line of code that starts "var obj =" The alert comes back as [object Object].  Is there a problem with the syntax?  Or maybe attr is the problem? The player is loading, but no playlist. Thanks for any help, Cheryl

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?  The alert is supposed to show `[object Object]` because that's what it is.

Comment: @climbage - Oh, ok -- I thought the alert would show the values.  The problem is that no playlist is being created.  The player loads, but no list.

Comment: console.log(obj) will tell you more than alert(obj). console.log will write in the console so you should read the message from the console of your browser.

Comment: @LajosArpad - thanks! So now I can see that the values in the obj variable are correct.  Not getting a playlist, however.  Mystery.

Comment: I don't think obj is the playlist, I believe a member of obj might be the playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above worked when I changed one line.  Instead of:

```
    playlist.push(obj);
```

I used:

```
    myPlaylist.add(obj);
```

et voila.